# Export POST Request from postman to Python

Tags: python, postman, quip

I am attempting to run a POST request in python. When I test in Postman it runs fine and imports the file. When I run it in Python I error out.  This posts a spreadsheet stored on my computer into Quip. I am getting the error missing argument 'file'. I have tried moving several things around and am not sure what im missing. here is what im working with:

```
import requests

url = "https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/import-file"

payload = {'type': 'spreadsheet'}
files = [
('file', open('/Users/admin/Documents/excel/logs/Output/test.xlsx','rb'))
]
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization': 'Bearer **************************='
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: if it runs in postman, how about getting the code from postman for python. you can get that using code button

Comment: The code I posted in my question is the output from Postman. Sorry I didn't clarify that. Thats why im scratching my head as to why it won't run

Comment: How about pycurl. Did you test that?

Comment: I am not familiar with pycurl

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line:

```py
files = {'file': open('/Users/admin/Documents/excel/logs/Output/test.xlsx','rb')}
```

Also I noticed a bug in Postman (version 9.9.1): payload contains only the first field. Be aware of that.

So I would not rely on generated code.